# Creating scrollbars with SVG and d3.js

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js, scrollbar

Right now I've used d3 to create several "boxes" that are merely SVG rectangles with text:

```
var canvas = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 800)
    .attr("height", 500);


//specifies drawing area for each box
var boxes = canvas.selectAll("rect")
    .data(classData)
    .enter();

boxes.append("rect")
        .attr("width", boxWidth)
        .attr("height", boxHeight)
        .attr("fill", boxColor)
        .attr("x", function (d, i) { return i * 2 * boxWidth });


text.append("text")
        .attr("fill", textColor)
        .attr("x", function (d, i) 
              { return i * 2 * boxWidth + 5 })
        .attr("y", 20)
        .style("width", "20px")
        .style("overflow-x", "scroll")
        .text(function(d) {return d.name});
```

[image]

Now what I'd like to do is add scrollbars to each box when the text is outside the bounds of the box. I've seen a couple examples that created a `div` and used CSS to handle the overflow. However, I will have multiple (variable) boxes and I'm not sure how to go about this.

Any suggestions?

-- UPDATE --

I was able to get scrollbars to appear by appending svg elements to a div that controls scrolling with CSS styles.

```
.container {
    height: 225px;
    width: 175px;
    border:2px solid #000;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

svg {
    display: block;
    width: 200%;
    height: 200%;
}
```

However, the scrolling seems to be affected only by the width and height percentages of the svg element rather than the rect element that is drawn in the div. In other words, if the rectangle is too large, you still can not scroll to see all of it, unless you increase the width and height of the svg element.

Is there a way I can have the div scroll based on what is drawn inside of it? Or should I try to somehow calculate and change the width and height attributes of the svg element?

[view the code here](https://jsfiddle.net/azkqyjp6/4/)

Comment: You will need to add divs to your document and position them on top of the svg. Set `overflow-y: scroll` on the divs.

Comment: @Incodeveritas Thanks for your reply! I think I've done what you've said here: jsfiddle.net/azkqyjp6/3 But I still have a couple questions. 1) The rectangle appears to be smaller than it should. Why is this happening, and how would I fix it? And 2) When I increased the height of the rectangle, it just gets clipped, and no scrollbar actually appears. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No you can't use rects. You need to append divs on the body and position them on top of the svg using absolute/fixed positioning.

Comment: You could calculate the width and height of the svg element to get your scrollbar working properly.  Is there a reason why you need to render the text as svg instead of just adding it directly to the div as html?

Answer (score 4):

Try to add the viewBox svg property:

```
var rectangle = container.append("svg")
    .attr("viewBox", "0,0,150,420")
    .append("rect")
    .attr("width", 150)
    .attr("height", 420)
    .attr("fill", "steelblue")
    .attr("x", 0)
    .attr("y", 0);
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/elchininet/n53crtez/)